# Makefile wildcard on windows

Tags: makefile

I am having issues with a Makefile on certain systems

```
SRC = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.s)
```

works when compiling in Azure Devops, but not when compiling on my local Windows 10 computer.

Changing the source to

```
SRC = \
    $(SRCDIR)/browser.c \
    $(SRCDIR)/main.c \

SRCS = $(SRCDIR)/data's
```

allows compilation without issue in both instances. I am wondering if it could be a dependency not being met, or `VPATH` getting in the way (although it is not used in my Makefile...

Comment: I know of no reason why `wildcard` function wouldn't work in GNU make on Windows, so you'll have to provide some details.  What does happen?  Saying "doesn't work" is not informative.  What is the value of `SRCDIR` when things don't work?  What version of GNU make are you using?

Comment: the value of SRCDIR is <F:/<ProjectPathNoSpaces>> If I echo the output with `wildcard` it is blank, if I echo it with all of the sources, it is built... Example makefile is https://github.com/networkfusion/altra64/blob/develop-cicd/Makefile

Comment: but looking upstream, perhaps it is this causing the problem... https://github.com/N64-tools/mips64-gcc-toolchain/blob/master/scripts/build/make-01-undefined-alloca.patch

Comment: I have no idea about that patch.  You can try building your own version of GNU make to see if that one works.  I would always avoid trying to use `echo` etc. to debug makefiles.  If you add `$(info SRC = $(SRC))` to your makefile (and for `SRCS`) what does it show?  Also note the pattern rules in the Makefile you link above are wrong: they are missing the `/` in `$(OBJDIR)%.o`, `$(SRCDIR)%.c`, and `$(SRCDIR)%.s`.

Comment: The problem was indeed with the upstream patch. I have removed it, and wildcard now works as expected. Thanks for the other tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was to do with a patch being applied to make. Removing the patch allowed `wildcard` to work as expected.